# GROOVY Loop - generate List of Lists

Tags: list, loops, groovy

This is what I am trying to do.

Inside a loop i am generating list items in the format [a,1]. First element is a string, second is a number.
Once I have all the lists from the loop, I need to put this in another list.
example -> [[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]]

This is my sample code I was trying albeit with just the int element. I am unfortunately not able to get what i am looking for. Should be something simple I am overlooking.

```
a = [1,2]
b = []
c = []
a.each
{
b.clear()
b.add(it)
println b
c.add(b)
}
println c
```

Output generated is

```
[1]
[2]
[[2], [2]]
```

I am trying to get

```
[1]
[2]
[[1], [2]]
```

EDIT

After help from Alexander

```
a = [1,2]
c = []
a.each
{
b = []
b.add(it)
c.add(b)
}
println c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You insert into c a reference to the same list twice. Hence you get what you put.
Try to replace `b.clear()` with `b = []`
Then it will be a new list.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions how I can get the output I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Came across an easier way to achieve this. Using collate()

```
a = [1,2]
a.collate(1)
```

Result
[[1],[2]]